# Italic Cursive/Running Resources

Tags: best-practice, font-design, technique, calligraphy

I am in the process of practicing a running Italic hand, with most letters connected in the spirit of [Paul Standard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0800803248) (I also own Alfred Fairbank's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0823021858)). In addition, I'm trying to minimise the number of pen lifts and write at high speed.

My ultimate goal is to make a font based on the writing.

I'm interested in examples and references about howtos and good practice (about the writing, *not* about the font design).

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS The keywords are poor but they're the best I could find  (I checked the entire list). I don't have enough reputation to add keywords *Italic* and *Calligraphy.* If somebody could add them for me, then that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: As it stands I don't think this is a good question. It would be better if instead of asking for resources you edit the question and ask us for tips and strategies directly. The more specific the better. We try to avoid resource request questions.

Comment: ps Are you at all related to Kees van Dongen? One of my favorite painters.